# Reactjs Add dynamic component into other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render

I am trying to develop a webapp using reactjs and i have a issue. After more than 1 day of research, i don't understand how to do.

I want to use a component which are the main layout of my page adding other component to display in it.

In the component Base2, the child props contains another component.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Base2 = (child) => (

    <div>
        <div className="top-bar">
            <div className="top-bar-left">
                <NavLink to="/">React App</NavLink>
            </div>

            <div className="top-bar-right">
                <Link to="/login">Log in</Link>
            </div>

        </div>

        <child/> // HERE the dynamic component

    </div>
);

export default Base2;
```

The function calling it is :

```
const TestBase = ({props}) => {
    return (<Base child={MyComponent}/>)
};
```

Moreover MyComponent can be a class declare following 2 methods:

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginForm from '../components/LoginForm.jsx';

class MyComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    ...
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <LoginForm
                onSubmit={this.processForm}
                onChange={this.changeUser}
                errors={this.state.errors}
                user={this.state.user}
            />
        );
    }

}

export default LoginPage;
```

Second method :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardTitle } from 'material-ui/Card';

const MyComponent = {
    render()  {
        return (<Card className="container">
            <CardTitle title="React Application" subtitle="Home         page." />
        </Card>);
    }
};

export default MyComponent ;
```

During my tests, only the second method works. The lack of "instance" (something like that i guess) from the second method might be the issue?
How can I develop Base2 component to take these 2 types of component declaration?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First pass the component like this:

```
<Base child={<MyComponent/>}/>
```

Then `render` it inside Base2 component by `props.child`, the way you wrote the Base2 component, child (just the argument name) will have the value of `props` not directly the component you are passing in `props`.

Write it like this:

```
const Base2 = (props) => ( 
    <div>
        <div className="top-bar">
            <div className="top-bar-left">
                <NavLink to="/">React App</NavLink>
            </div>

            <div className="top-bar-right">
                <Link to="/login">Log in</Link>
            </div>
        </div>

        {props.child}   //here

    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank for you quick reply.

With these modifications, only the second method works.
I really want to know why it works in one case and not for the second.
Do you have any strategy for both method?
Does both methods return the same output? I don't think so because only one way is correct. That is why i don't understand alone.

Comment: Actually, you show me the correct way because thanks to your response, i succeeded with both method. I answer to my question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the second method seems to be a simple json containing a render method. To create component in your second method which seems to be wrote in es5 you have to use react.createClass({ render ... })
Seek on internet you will find a lot of es5 example

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Mayank Shukla i found the best way to do.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Base2 = (props) => (

    <div>
        <div className="top-bar">
            <div className="top-bar-left">
                <NavLink to="/">React App</NavLink>
            </div>

            <div className="top-bar-right">
                <Link to="/login">Log in</Link>
            </div>

        </div>

        {props.child}

    </div>
);

export default Base2;
```

The function calling it is :

```
const TestBase = (props) => {
    return (<Base2 child={<MyComponent/>}/>)
};
```

First Method:

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginForm from '../components/LoginForm.jsx';

class MyComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    ...
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <LoginForm
                onSubmit={this.processForm}
                onChange={this.changeUser}
                errors={this.state.errors}
                user={this.state.user}
            />
        );
    }

}

export default LoginPage;
```

Second method :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardTitle } from 'material-ui/Card';

const MyComponent = (props) =>{

        return (<Card className="container">
            <CardTitle title="React Application" subtitle="Home         page." />
        </Card>);

};

export default MyComponent ;
```